# why does TCP over VXLAN in mininet stop sending after switching tunnel?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, mininet, traffic-simulation, vxlan

[topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0F0n.png)
This is my experimental setup in Mininet. VM1 and VM2 are separate Virtualbox VM instances running on my computer connected by Bridged adapter, and S1 and S2 are connected with vxlan forwarding.

Then I used D-ITG on H1 and H2 to generate traffic. I send TCP traffic from H1 to H2 and use wireshark to capture. During a 10sec TCP flow, I used a python script that changes the tunnel id of the first rule on S1 from 100 to 200.

If the packet/sec rate and payload size is small enough, the TCP session does not seem to be affected, but when I start sending around 100 packet/sec each with payload of 64 bytes, TCP stop sending after receiving a dup ACK. Here is the wireshark capture:
[wireshark1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrEb9.png)
[wireshark2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG75g.png)

On the link between H1 and S1 I received ICMP destination unreachable (fragmentation needed).

After the two errors, TCP stopped sending. I understand that the "previous segment not captured" is caused by the fact that when I alter the S1 routing table, there is some down time and packets are dropped by the switch. However, I don't understand why TCP does not initiate retransmission.

This does not happen if I reduce the packet rate or the payload to a smaller amount, or if I use UDP. Is this an issue with the TCP stack, or maybe D-ITG? Or maybe it is an issue with the sequence numbers? Is there a range where if very previous packets are not ACKed, they will not be retransmitted?

This problem has been bothering me for a while, so I hope someone here can maybe provide some clarification. Thanks a lot for reading XD.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected it may be a problem with mininet NICs, so I tried to disable TCP fragmentation offload, and it worked much better. I suppose that the virtual NICs in mininet in a VM could not handle the large amount of traffic generated by D-ITG, so using TCP fragmentation offload can overload? the NIC and cause segmentation errors.

This is just my speculation, but disabling TSO did help my case. Additional input is welcomed!